# Placing Order algorithm (Rest API not Controller)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, place-order

Which `Controller` (or `php` class) is actually responsible for placing an order?

Seems the following JS components are initiating the `post` request:

Checkout Page -> Payment Button

```
Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default.js
Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order.js
Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order.js
```

But I don't know what controller (or php class) is responsible for actually handling the `placeOrder` request.

Comment: Do You mean Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder ?

Comment: @Konrad-Siamro: Thanks for your answer, but seems it's not being used anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following class is responsible for placing order from checkout page

```
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement
```

Find **placeOrder** method.

**How it call?**

Open **Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js**,

It's call 
'carts/mine/payment-information' OR 'guest-carts/:quoteId/payment-information'

that means **Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php** **savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder** method.

[Check here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php#L69)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for the controller my friend.

Comment: No controller here, It's REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Interesting! But 2 questions: 1) What is `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder` doing?  2) how does `carts/mine/payment-information` is calling `Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder `?

Comment: Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder -> no use any more.

Comment: Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/etc/webapi.xml#L80

Comment: Hello @sohel Is it possible save payment method without place order ?