# Intercept Onepage\SaveOrder

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I'm trying to add a certain process in the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder` so I decided to implement a plugin for that. But after creating the di.xml and the classes needed when I try to purchase an item and fill out all the shipping details and selected the needed payment method. Upon submission of the order, I was expecting the function to be run. But somehow it's not being called. Can any help me with this or if anyone has any idea what I did wrong. Below are my codes

> content of  di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder">
        <plugin name="Custom_Module_Plugin" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\SaveOrderPlugin" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> content of SaveOrderPlugin.php

```
<?php 
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin;

class SaveOrderPlugin
{   
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        // logging to test override    
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug("********** " . __METHOD__ . ' - ' . __LINE__);

        // call the core observed function
        $returnValue = $proceed(); 

        // logging to test override        
        $logger->debug("********** " . __METHOD__ . ' - ' . __LINE__);

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see I was expecting an output in the console log as shown below but this does not show. Also, I tried intercepting other classes like `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement` and it worked as expected. But the reason I want to override the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder` is primarily that I want to retrieve a certain parameter when the order of item is submitted.

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong here?

Comment: Hello , this link might help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157845/placing-order-algorithm-rest-api-not-controller